# Getting numpy array from generator

Tags: python, numpy, generator

Is there am filling a numpy array as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import bct as bct

mri_thresh = np.linspace(0.2, 0.07, 20)
W = np.random.rand(40,40)
W_bin = np.zeros([40, 40 , len(mri_thresh)])

i = 0
for thresh in mri_thresh:
    W_bin[:, :, i] = (bct.threshold(W, thresh)>0)
    i = i+1
```

It seems there is a more concise way to achieve much the same

```
W_bin = [(bct.threshold_proportional(W, thresh)>0 for thresh in mri_thresh)]
```

But here I get a generator. My question is is there a way to have this produce a numpy array rather than a generator using similar code?

Comment: dont use the curved bracket, just the square ones. This is the difference between list comprehension and generator expression surrounded by a square bracket.

Comment: @Paritoshsingh is correct, but you also dont get an array at the end, the list comprehension would give you a list of arrays

Comment: `np.fromiter` can produce a 1d array from a generator, but `np.array` requires a list - i.e. `np.array(list(your_generator))`.

Comment: thanks, this works: W_bin = np.array([bct.threshold_proportional(W, thresh)>0 for thresh in mri_thresh]